# Finding salary of all the employee of all the supervisor where supervisor can have supervisor

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-cte

**Problem**

I have two tables. `employee` and `salary`.
For the `employee` table I have `employee_id` and `supervisor_id`.

| employee_id | supervisor_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | NULL |
| 8 | NULL |

For the `salary` table I have `amount` and `employee_id`.

| employee_id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 500 |
| 6 | 600 |
| 7 | 1000 |
| 8 | 1000 |

**Question**

For the supervisor with no supervisor (in my case employee id 7 and 8) I want to get the mean of sum of salary of all the employees that are working under them. So, for 7, it would be employee 5,2,1 and 0 and for employee 8 it would be 6,4 and 3.

I have tried using recursive cte but haven't been able to make much progress with it

```
WITH RECURSIVE supervisor_tree AS (
  SELECT e.id, e.supervisor_id, (SELECT f.amount FROM salary f WHERE f.employee_id= e.id) AS amount
  FROM employees e
  WHERE e.supervisor_id IS NULL -- only top-level supervisors
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.id, e.supervisor_id, COALESCE(f.weight, 0) AS weight
  FROM employees e
  INNER JOIN salary f ON e.id = f.employee_id
  INNER JOIN supervisor_tree st ON e.supervisor_id = st.id
)
SELECT supervisor_id, weight 
FROM supervisor_tree;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE employee_paths (employee_id, path) AS
(
  SELECT employee_id, ARRAY[employee_id]
    FROM employees
    WHERE supervisor_id is null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.employee_id, path || e.employee_id
    FROM employee_paths AS ep 
    JOIN employees AS e ON e.supervisor_id = ep.employee_id
),
cte as (
  SELECT e.employee_id as supervisor_id, ep.employee_id
  FROM employees e
  INNER JOIN employee_paths ep on e.employee_id =ANY(ep.path)
  order by e.employee_id
)
select supervisor_id, round(AVG(amount),2)
from cte c
inner join salary s on s.employee_id = c.employee_id
where c.supervisor_id <> c.employee_id
group by supervisor_id
order by supervisor_id
```

The `employee_path` gets all supervisors of employees, then the second `cte` to get all the employees that are working under every supervisor.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7kqjjBxP)